# Different answers from `NSurfaceIntegrate` if using `ImplicitRegion`

Tags: numerical-integration

I want to find the surface area of a region defined as $x^2+y^2\le1$ and $z=ln(x^2+y^2+2)$.
I can transform it into cylindrical coordinates and write $z=ln(r^2+2)$. Using `ParametricRegion` gives:

```mathematica
NSurfaceIntegrate[1,{x,y,z} ∈ ParametricRegion[{r Cos[t],r Sin[t],Log[r^2+2]},{{r,0,1},{t,0,2Pi}}]]
(* 3.5618 *)
```

This also matches the answer I get from symbolic computation (a bit slow) and turning the answer to numerical form:

```mathematica
Area[{r Cos[t],r Sin[t],Log[r^2+2]},{r,0,1},{t,0,2Pi}] // N
(* 3.5618 *)
```

But when I use `NSurfaceIntegrate` on `ImplicitRegion`, it returns a slightly off answer:

```mathematica
NSurfaceIntegrate[1,{x,y,z} ∈ ImplicitRegion[x^2+y^2<=1 && z==Log[x^2+y^2+2],{x,y,z}]]
(* 3.56125 *)
```

Why is this occuring? Is it because it will convert `ImplicitRegion` to an approximate representation with polygons? I haven't found anything in the documentation about this. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica StackExchange! `NSurfaceIntegrate` is quite new and still an experimental function, so it might be buggy (or missing some features) ... For example, changing `WorkingPrecision` should affect the result (as presented in the documentation), but it doesn't work for `ImplicitRegion`s.

Comment: Moreover, `Area[ImplicitRegion[
  x^2 + y^2 <= 1 && z == Log[x^2 + y^2 + 2], {x, y, z}]]` outputs `Undefined` and `RegionMeasure[
 ImplicitRegion[x^2 + y^2 <= 1 && z == Log[x^2 + y^2 + 2], {x, y, z}],
  2]` performs `Infinity` though `Dimensions[
 ImplicitRegion[x^2 + y^2 <= 1 && z == Log[x^2 + y^2 + 2], {x, y, z}]]` results in `{2}`. I think  `ImplicitRegion` makes troubles, not `NSurfaceIntegrate`.